# JSON String Indices Must Be Integers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

There are a number of questions with this subject, but most seem to be people forgetting to call `json.loads`.

Here is my example:

```
import json

json_input = '{ "ar": { "articles": { "12345": {"title": "first title" } , "67890": {"title": "another title" } } } } '

data = json.loads(json_input)

for article in data['ar']['articles']:
    print(article['title'])
```

The call to print fails with the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Always post the full traceback ... It will be more helpful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are currently printing is the key for the article dict, and not the article's title itself. If you print article in your example, it will print the keys

```
In [6]: for article in data['ar']['articles']:
        print(article)
   ...:     
67890
12345
```

To print the article's title, iterate on the items within the dict:

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: json_input = '{ "ar": { "articles": { "12345": {"title": "first title" } , "67890": {"title": "another title" } } } } '

In [3]: data = json.loads(json_input)

In [4]: for article in data['ar']['articles'].values():
   ...:     print(article['title'])
   ...:     
another title
first title
```

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but I'd suggest iterating over the `values` (or `itervalues` in Python 2) rather than the `items` of the dictionary, since you don't need the key at all.

Comment: @mu無 - I get an error with your code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    for _key, article in data['ar']['articles'].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @Blckknght its not the -1 I mind, its the absence of any reasons that makes it seem bizarre. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out, I realized I needed the switch  also because python3 doesn't have `.iteritems`.

Comment: Worked for me thank you very much the .values() did the trick !